# AttributeError: 'Nonetype' object has no attribute 'enter' python

Tags: python, oop

I'm learning python with learn python the hard way and I'm making a 'game' using dict and classes. The code is incomplete, but the main problem is the AttributeError.

I'm stuck with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "juego.py", line 86, in <module>
    juego.play()
  File "juego.py", line 60, in play
    game.enter()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'enter'
```

The code:

```
class entry(): #OK
   def enter(self):
       print 'Llegaste a la primera habitacion, miras a tu alrededor...'
       print 'y ves un boton rojo en la pared...'
       print 'Que haces?'
       print 'Apretas el boton?'
       print 'O seguis mirando?'
       boton_rojo = raw_input('> ')
       if 'boton' in boton_rojo:
           print 'Apretas el boton y...'
           print 'Aparece una puerta adelante tuyo!'
           return  'Rescate_Prisionero'
       elif 'mir' in boton_rojo:
           print 'Seguis mirando...'
           print '...'
           print 'no encontras nada y decidis apretar el boton rojo'
           print 'Apretas el boton y...'
           print 'Aparece una puerta adelante tuyo!'
       else:
           print 'eh? que dijiste?'


class rescate_prisionero():
   def enter(self):
       print 'parece que si'
       return 'Mago_Poderoso'

class mago_poderoso():
   def enter(self):
       print 'trolo'
       return 'Pelea_esqueleto'

class pelea_esqueleto():
   def enter(self):
       print 'esque'
       return 'Habitacion_Vacia'

class habitacion_vacia():
   def enter(self):
      print 'vac'
      return 'Final_Scene'

class final_scene():
   def enter(self):
      print 'parece que esta todo bien'


class Engine(object):
   def __init__(self, primer_escena):
   self.primer_escena = primer_escena

   def play(self):
      ultima_escena = Map.Escenas.get('Final_Scene')
      game =self.primer_escena.arranque().enter()
      while game != ultima_escena:
         game = Map.Escenas.get(game)
         game.enter()



class Map():
   def __init__(self, primer_escena):
   self.primer_escena = primer_escena

   def arranque(self):
     inicio = Map.Escenas.get(self.primer_escena)
     return inicio





 Escenas = { 'Entry' : Entry(),
             'Rescate_Prisionero' : rescate_prisionero(),
             'Mago_Poderoso' : mago_poderoso(),
             'Pelea_esqueleto' : pelea_esqueleto(),
             'Habitacion_Vacia' : habitacion_vacia(),
             'Final_Scene' : final_scene()
 }

 pepe = Map('Entry')
 juego = Engine(pepe)
 juego.play()
```

EDIT: sorry, I forgot the error, the code is NOW complete

Comment: You forgot to give us the error message.

Comment: You also forgot to post the whole code.  `Entry` is undefined.

Comment: I add the error, the code is complete

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because at some point `game` becomes the `None` object. This can happen at a number of different steps, so it might be hard to track down. Any time you call `dict.get` you are returning `None` if the key isn't found.

It's probably easiest to change all your `dict.get(key)` statements to `dict[key]` statements. There doesn't appear to be any way to proceed if the dictionary doesn't contain the key, so throwing a `KeyError` is definitely better than suppressing the error until later.

It's also possible that one or more of your `Map.Escenas` values are actually `None`, so even if `dict.get` is finding the value, it's returning a `None`. This is why using `dict[key]` is helpful here -- at least you can narrow it down! You didn't include any of the code from any of the functions:

```
Entry
rescate_prisionero
mago_poderoso
pelea_esqueleto
habitacion_vacia
final_scene
```

So there's no way for us to check that here.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add that. the code is now complete, thank you for your answer, I'm gonna try